# Threading module

Tags: python, multithreading

Have a question, I'm some new in threading, I made this code....

```
import threading
from colorama import *
import random
import os

listax = [Fore.GREEN,Fore.YELLOW,Fore.RED]
print(random.choice(listax))

def hola():
    import requests
    a = requests.get('https://google.com')
    print(a.status_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=hola)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=hola)
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=hola)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

And output shows 3 times if I execute 3 times the code, but my question is, for example, if I have big code and all start in:

```
def main():
    code...
```

How I can add multiple threading for fast work, I see I can add 1 thread, if I add 3 threads the output shows 3 times, but how I can do it for example for add 10 threads to the same task without the output repeating 10 times for this execute fast as possible using the resourses of the system?

Comment: I suggest you use a [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) to easily control how many threads there are at any one time. You can submit as many "jobs" as you want, but the pool's size will determine how many of them are allowed to run at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading does not magically sped up your code. It's up to you to break the code in chunks that can be run concurrently. When you create 3 threads that run `hola`, you are not "running `hola` once using 3 threads", but you are "running `hola` three times, each time in a different thread.

Although multithreading *can* be used to perform computation in parallel, the most common python interpreter (CPython) is implemented using a lock (the GIL) that lets only one thread run at a time. There are libraries that release the GIL before doing CPU-intensive work, so threading in python **is** useful for doing CPU-intensive work. Moreover, I/O operations relese the gil, so multithreading in python is very well suited for I/O work.

As an example, let's imagine that you have to need to access three different sites. You can access them sequentially, one after the other:

```
import requests

sites = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://rae.es']

def hola(site):
    a = requests.get(site)
    print(site, " answered ", a.status_code)

for s in sites:
    hola(s)
```

Or concurrently (all at the same time) using threads:

```
import requests
import threading

sites = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://rae.es']

def hola(site):
    a = requests.get(site)
    print(site, " answered ", a.status_code)

th = [threading.Thread(target=hola, args=(s, )) for s in sites]
for t in th:
    t.start()
for t in th:
    t.join()
```

Please note that this is a simple example: the output can get scrambled, you have no acces to the return values, etc. For this kind of tasks I would use a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a for loop.

number_of_threads is the number of how many threads u want to run

```
for _ in range(number_of_threads):

    t = threading.Thread(target=hola)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Comment: You can not join before starting!

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use the loop of the code you give me

```
# Python program to illustrate the concept
# of threading
# importing the threading module
import threading
from colorama import *
import random
import os

listax = [Fore.GREEN,Fore.YELLOW,Fore.RED]
print(random.choice(listax))

"""
def print_cube(num):
    function to print cube of given num
    print("Cube: {}".format(num * num * num))
"""  
def print_square():
    num = 2
    """
    function to print square of given num
    """
    print("Square: {}".format(num * num))
def hola():
    import requests
    a = requests.get('https://google.com')
    print(a.status_code)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for j in range(10):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=hola)
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

but when i run the code the code run 1 print per time, in my case give me
200
1 sec later again 200
and 200 again (x 10 times because i added 10 thread)

but i want know how i can do for this execute as fast possible without show me the 10 output, just i want the code do 1 print but as fast possible with 10 thread for example

Comment: well, you did not ask for it you just asked for a script that can add multiple threads with EZ.

Comment: you can parallelize the hola function you cant run the hola function with 10 threads that's not how it is working. In python, you cant assign a function 10 threads so that 10 threads execute one instance of hola. If u add one new Thread running hola it runs hola as a copy and not the same hola a the other Thread