# Threading python

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing, instagram

I'm making a bot that parses subscribers of the entered account to log into the category of business accounts and for the presence of an avatar. I want to do parsing in four threads, but it turns out that the loop just runs four times. tell me how to do it correctly

```
import instaloader
import threading

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
L.login(login, password) # (log in)

nickname = str(input('Enter a nickname '))
# Checking followers without pic
followers_no_pic = []
# Checking the list of subscribers on existing business accounts
check_business = []
# Create list of followers
followers_list = []

print(f'Analysisof user {nickname}'
      f'\nThe process may take some time, please wait')

# NICK FROM USER
Profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, nickname)


def s(num):
    for followers in Profile.get_followers():
        followers_list.append(followers.username)

        account = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, followers.username)
        if account.is_business_account is True:
            check_business.append(account.is_business_account)
        pic = account.profile_pic_url
        pic = str(pic)
        print('P r o c e s s')

        if "https://instagram" in pic:
            followers_no_pic.append(pic)

        else:
            pass

t1 = threading.Thread(target=s, args=(0.1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=s, args=(0.1,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=s, args=(0.1,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=s, args=(0.1,))

s(1)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()


print(f'User {nickname}'f'\nNumber of subscribers: {len(followers_list)}')

print(f'\nWithout pics: {len(followers_no_pic)}')

print(f'\nBusiness Accounts: {len(check_business)}')

# bot analytics: account name, number of subscribers, subscribers without avatars and business accounts
```

Comment: You cant run your function "s" with 4 threads running the same function. You cant assign multiple threads to a function in python. It will always run the same function 4 times and not 4 threads the same function

Comment: The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803922/threading-module) to this question might help you  understand why this runs 4 times

Comment: @gerda die gandalfziege I understand that. the question is how to distribute the parsing load on all threads

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Threadpool that splits the processing in this example into 4 threads so you can give it a list of inputs and a function and it will run 4 Threads parallel until all items in the input list got processed.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool(processes=4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(s, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    print(results)
```